# iOS Application Support directory exists on devices by default

Tags: swift

Looking through SO it appears that the Application Support folder is not created on simulators by default:

[iOS: Can't save file to 'Application Support' folder, but can to 'Documents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204988/ios-cant-save-file-to-application-support-folder-but-can-to-documents)

But is it created on devices? Or do we need to createDirectory for applicationSupportDirectory, and when we use

```
fileManager.createDirectory(at: applicationSupportURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
```

are we guaranteed that if there are files within the folder that they are not deleted? I can't find a reference in the documentation for either question.

Comment: Never assume any file or folder exists. Check and create as needed.

Answer (score 3):

You are always responsible for creating the directory.

A convenient way is the API to get the current URL with set `create` parameter.

```
let applicationSupportDirectoryURL = try! fileManager.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

I can confirm the same on iOS 16 simulator under Xcode 14. On first run "Application Support" seems not existent and [vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5044042/vadian) code fixes correctly.

Comment: The question is asking about on device. The OP already knows it doesn't exist in a simulator.

Comment: I did read the note, I simply added that nothing has been changed since 3 years and 7 month.